# How to give multiple GDB commands through subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gdb

I need to give Gdb commands after I have started running a shell script which invokes gdb and halts to the Gdb prompt. So, to load and execute the image (.elf) file I invoke the following subprocess:

```
import subprocess
os.chdir(r"/project/neptune_psv/fw/")
print os.getcwd()

proc = subprocess.Popen('./Execute.sh -i TestList_new.in -m 135.20.230.160 -c mpu',shell = True,stdin = subprocess.PIPE)
```

After Execute.sh halts to the Gdb prompt I need to give two Gdb commands:

1. Set *0x44880810 = 3 (Set a register value)
2. Continue

Can anyone help me how to give these two commands through stdin ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to use something like `pexpect`, an expect clone in Python.  This provides a way to control an otherwise interactive process programmatically.

However, since you're specifically using `gdb`, note that this is not the best approach to driving gdb.  There are two better ways.  First, you can program gdb directly using its built-in Python API.  This is the best way, if it is possible for your use case, as it is a lot simpler than trying to parse the output.  However, if you must parse the output, then you should investigate "MI".  This is gdb's "Machine Interface", which presents a vaguely JSON-like (it predates the real JSON) way to control gdb.  There are MI parsing libraries available, though offhand I don't recall if there is one written in Python.