# How to simulate line break(keyboard enter) with Linux fd stdin

Tags: linux, stdin

Now we want to control the stdin of the running process by using Linux fd files. Here is the code.

```
import os, sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Try commands below")
  print("$ echo 'foobar' > /proc/{0}/fd/0".format(os.getpid()))
  import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
  while True:
    print("read :: [" + sys.stdin.readline() + "]")
    pass
```

We can open another terminal to echo strings info `/proc/$pid/fd/0` and the first terminal will show the input. But we can not input the "enter" signal which is like the real keyboard press.

We have try `echo -en "\n"` which will only input the new line but not "keyboard enter".

Comment: `echo -en "\n"` is the same as `echo ""`. The `'\n'` produced by pressing `[Enter]` after the `echo` command is not written to `stdout` and thus not piped to your program. No different than typing `cp file_a file_b`. There is no `[Enter]` magically directed to `stdout`, it is consumed by the shell when invoking the executable indicating the end of arguments to the process you just started.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination and actually we have try `echo -en "\n\n"`. Is that possible to "invoking the executable indicating the end of arguments to the process" by sending input to stdin?

Comment: Sure, but use `printf` as it gives better control. Simply `printf "\n\n"`.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `printf '\n\n' > /proc/$pd/fd/0` but it passed new lines instead of "invoking the executable indicating the end of arguments to the process".

Comment: Well, yes. Think of it this way, when you invoke `printf` -- what is the executable? (`printf`) That is the only executable that would have a chance to catch the `'\n'` generated by pressing `[Enter]` -- and only then if it were performing a *Read* of `stdin` in a way that allowed it to process the `'\n'` (like reading with `getchar()` or `fgets()` or `fgetc(stdin)` in C). What exactly are you trying to catch the `'\n'` produced by `[Enter]` with?

Comment: Thanks and I get it now. We can process `\n` when reading from `stdin`. However, we want to use this in `pdb` or `gbd` which still needs `[Enter]` to invoke the command instead of reading `\n` in `stdin`.

Comment: @tobe I had the same problem with `gdb` too. At the end I used the `pexpect` module as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604967/how-to-give-multiple-gdb-commands-through-subprocess